# Can 8 foot tall 2" x 2" furring strips attached to a floor plate and joists hold a 60 lb water heater?

Tags: studs, tankless, load

I'm trying to hang a 60lb tankless water heater in my basement against an exterior wall and trying to figure out if I can get away with 2" x 2" pine furring strips and some plywood.

Assuming minimal knots, **What is the maximum amount of weight I should assume an 8' 2" x 2" can bear at center (4' high) if attached to a secured floor plate and overhead joist?**

Thanks!

Comment: There’s 2x2’s will be mounted to the wall? What material is the exterior wall made of? How will you attach to the wall? How will you attach to the 2x2’s? What is the weight and capacity of you water heater? A better question would be “Will this configuration work?” or “How would you hang this heater onto this wall?”.

Comment: The answer varies wildly with the actual 2x2. With a board that small, knots can cut load capacity by 90%. At any rate, you're asking about studs. Studs don't carry weight "on center", as they're oriented vertically. Please add more detail to your question so we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: fyi a 2x2 isn't a stud, its referred to as a furring strip.  Presumably this is secured to a concrete wall or something?? Details please.

Comment: @Stanwood  As per the stack exchange guidelines, I'm trying to avoid subjective questions and instead focus on getting the abstract answers that would provide my self and others the fundamental knowledge needed to solve an array of different but similar problems.

Comment: @isherwood While crawling the internet I once saw a load bearing chart that gave weight by per foot, as well as max load at center, sadly I can't find it now, and it probably didn't included 'strapping' anyway.

Comment: @agentp Thanks, clearly the distance between support structures will matter, sorry I left that out.

Comment: @Stanwood FYI, I'm not being stubborn, it's just that the amount of plumbing that is embedded into the concrete (against and off set from the wall) that I'm trying to frame around makes it hard to describe and take pictures of my situation, and means it's pretty custom.  I might end up mixing strapping and studs if I can figure out what kind of loads I can handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical install would us 2x4's with plywood across. Basically mimic wood stud framing. Doing the same with 2x2's should be fine for this application. I'm assuming a 100lb dead load. Use 23/32" sheathing plywood or MDF. Mount with nuts/bolts into the plywood and framing nails elsewhere. Weak point would be tearout of a connector not deflection of the 2x2 beams. If you are paranoid you can use metal wood ties to enable bolts elsewhere rather than toenails. I think once you hang the 2x2s from floor to ceiling you will see they are plenty strong enough to hold a grown adult.

I included a picture that I think represents what you are trying to do except behind this plywood/frame would be a basement wall with pipes you don't want to attach to.

[image: Example plywood framing]